# How to change the main menu event from a default click on it to the navigation of the mouse arraow?

Tags: navigation

How to change the main menu event from click to navigation? I want to make submenus of the main menu to respond on mouse arrow navigation not on a click which is default. What is a rational way to change it? Does it depend on a patriclular  theme?

Answer (score 1):

Use contributed module like:

- [Nice menus](https://www.drupal.org/project/nice_menus)

> Nice Menus enables drop-down/right/left expandable menus. It uses only
>   CSS for most browsers, with minimal Javascript for IE6. (Version 2
>   uses the Superfish jQuery plugin for all browsers, with an option to
>   disable JS, and falls back to CSS-only for browsers that can handle
>   it.)
>
> Three styles/types of menus are currently possible: horizontal, menus
>   drop down; vertical, menus fly to the left; vertical, menus fly to the
>   right. There is a handbook page that provides a list of sites that use
>   Nice menus.

- [Megamenu](https://www.drupal.org/project/megamenu)

> Mega menus are a type of drop-down, which seeks to overcome some of
>   the usability drawbacks of traditional drop-downs. Hierarchy of your
>   navigation is made visible all at once and the amount of clicking,
>   searching, and navigating is reduced.
>
> This module allows you to build mega menus by leveraging jQuery and
>   the existing Drupal menu system. Megamenu takes a Drupal menu that is
>   3 levels deep, and converts it into a categorized 3-level mega menu,
>   which is placed into your site as a block.

- [TB Mega Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu)

> TB Mega Menu allows you to create a mega menu with an innovative
>   back-end user interface and synchronized with Drupal core menu.
>
> We strive for more improvement each release, and your feedback on this
>   module is extremely important to us.

Comment: I've edited your post to include a little more detail. Links to the modules so they are easier to find and a short description from the module page. It will be easier for the OP to find the module and see if it works. Thanks for your contribution.